# Removing Duplicate Records from table based on a column

Tags: database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing Duplicate row from a table based on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183706/removing-duplicate-row-from-a-table-based-on-one-column)

I created a table with multiple inner joins from 4 tables but the results brings back duplicate records. Here is code that I am using

```
  DataSet quotetobepostedlist = DataRepository.Provider.ExecuteDataSet(System.Data.CommandType.Text,
      "Select  tblLoadStop.LoadID
           , tblCustomer.CustomerID
           ,tblLoadMaster.Salesperson
           ,OriginationState
           , DestinationState
           ,LoadRate
      FROM tblLoadMaster 
      INNER JOIN tblLoadSpecifications ON tblLoadSpecifications.LoadID=tblLoadMaster.LoadID  
      INNER JOIN  tblLoadStop ON tblLoadStop.LoadID=tblLoadMaster.LoadID 
      INNER JOIN tblStopLocation ON tblStopLocation.StopLocationID=tblLoadStop.StopLocationID  
      INNER JOIN tblCustomer ON tblCustomer.CustomerID =tblLoadMaster.CustomerID 
      WHERE tblLoadMaster.Phase LIKE '%2%' 
      ORDER BY tblLoadMaster.LoadID DESC;");
```

This is the result that I get

```
Load ID   Customer   Salesperson     Origin  Destination     Rate    
13356     FedEx           Alex           Duluth    New York     300
13356     FedEx           Steve          Florida   Kansas       400
```

I only want the first row to show,

```
13356     FedEx           Alex           Duluth    New York     300
```

and remove the bottom row,

```
13356     FedEx           Steve          Florida   Kansas       400
```

Comment: So what exactly do you expect to get?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?